# A problem with two を in this sentence

Tags: verbs, readings, particle-を

I was reading a web novel and this sentence shows up (I post the whole paragraph).

> ホームルームが終わると、一年生は体育館に集合させられていた。これから部活動紹介が始まるのである。その中で栞は周りをきょろきょろと見まわしていた。部活動紹介**を**目を輝かせて期待を寄せる者、体育館での集合に退屈であくび連発をする者など、様々な生徒たちの反応が見える。

I don't undestand to what verb links the bold を with 部活動紹介. To my knowledge, a verb can take only one を, so:
目を links with 輝かせて;
期待を寄せる is a set expression;
あくびを with 連発する.

So the first を with what verb links to?

**Context:** after the Home Room lesson, the first grade children of a middle school are brought to the gym to choose a club, and the main characther 栞 is looking around.

Comment: I believe this is a simple typo. The correct particle is に (部活動紹介**に**期待を寄せる).

Comment: Or it's simply poorly written.

Comment: It's on a free novel reading website, so the chance that it's a typo/poor written is high. At least I can training my error perception skill.